# How to get the standard sync button to update when starting a sync in apex

Tags: apex, quote, sync

I have updated the SyncedQuoteId on the opportunity and the quote IsSyncing field has updated to true, but I would like the "Start Sync" button on the standard quote layout page to update to "Stop Sync".  Any idea what I need to update to get it to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found that what I was doing actually updates the button.  In the org I was working in there is something that if you refresh the quote it is saving it and was saving over the syncedquoteid I was populating so it was turning that off.